# QT C++ How can I inform the user after the QSerialPort reading process is finished?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have a program that reads data over the serial port. I am collecting the incoming data into a buffer and the incoming data has no fixed value. I want to notify the user after the data is finished reading How can I do this?

Here I check if data is coming through the serial port. How can I check this after all the data is in?

```
serialInput = serial.getString();
  serial.clearAll();

  serialInput = serialInput.trimmed();

  if (serialInput.isEmpty() == false) {
    parser.parse(serialInput, 0 == 0, 0 == 2); 
    QStringList labelList = parser.getStringListLabels();
    QList < double > numericDataList = parser.getListNumericValues();


    QList < long > timeStamps = parser.getListTimeStamp();

    this -> processChart(labelList, numericDataList, timeStamps);

    this -> saveToRAM(labelList, numericDataList, timeStamps);

  }
}
```

Comment: I assume serialInput = serialInput.trimmed(); is the variable that holds incoming data. So, if it is not empty- serialInput.isEmpty() == false-  you are processing it in your code. I think, adding an else statement shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using `QSerialPort` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html) but just in case there is a signal `void QIODevice::readyRead()` that you can use to know if datas are available to read. From there you can emit a new custom signal right after you read it.

`bool QIODevice::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)` might also be useful.

You can find examples here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-examples.html.